# MVC2 complains that it cannot find a public action method on a controller, even though it's there

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using MVC2 with VS2008, and the following piece of code in the view ~/Shared/Site.Master:

```
<ul id="navlist">
            <li class="first"><a href="<%= Url.Content("~")%>" id="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Content("~/Store/")%>">Store</a></li>
            <li>
                **<% Html.RenderAction("CartSummary","ShoppingCart"); %></li>**
            <li><a href="<%= Url.Content("~/StoreManager/") %>">Admin</a></li>
        </ul>
```

throws the following exception:

> Error executing child request for handler
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

which has this inner exception:

> "A public action method 'CartSummary' was not found on controller
>   'MvcMusicStore.Controllers.ShoppingCartController'."

... that doesn't make any sense. The "CartSummary" method is defined as follows:

```
// GET: /ShoppingCart/CartSummary
[NHibernateActionFilter]
[ChildActionOnly]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CartSummary()
{
    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext, this.NSession);

    ViewData["CartCount"] = cart.GetCount();

    return PartialView("CartSummary");
}
```

So what gives? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens if you remove the [HttpGet] attribute from your child action?

If i am correct the child action will be called with the same HTTP Verb as the "main action" was called.

Comment: That did the trick. But the main action also is a GET, so what gives?

Comment: Always or there is a Post version of it or maybe a fully different action with HttpPost attribute which ViewResults uses this partial view? (For example when you put something in the shopping cart.)

Answer (score 0):

@Cosmo...is the name of your controller 'ShoppingCartController' or ShoppingCart.  If it's 'ShoppingCartController', then the html.RenderAction will barf as the Controller name will be incorrect.

Change to:
Html.RenderAction("CartSummary","ShoppingCartController");

Comment: Yes, the controller is named ShoppingCartController, and as per your advice, I changed the RenderAction's 2nd parameter value to "ShoppingCartController", which gives me the following exception:{"The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController."}

Comment: Controller is implied at the end of every MVC controller name, and doesn't need to be explicitly appended.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Html.RenderAction` to `Html.Action` or remove the `[ChildActionOnly]` filter